# Not able to alias column name in nested case using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

In this code its able to alias each case statement separately like,

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN (a.place = 'CHN' AND a.salary = 20000)  
              THEN '1' 
              ELSE '0' 
        END) AS '20K Salary',
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN (a.place = 'CHN' and a.salary = 35000)  
              THEN '1' 
              ELSE '0' 
        END) AS '35K Salary'
FROM Employee a;
```

but when nested `CASE` statement is used,

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN (a.place = 'CHN') 
              THEN (CASE 
                       WHEN a.salary = 20000  
                          THEN '1' 
                          ELSE '0' 
                    END) AS '20K Salary',
                   (CASE 
                       WHEN a.salary = 35000  
                          THEN '1' 
                          ELSE '0' 
                    END) AS '35K Salary'
        END) 
FROM Employee a;
```

its not possible to execute the query

Comment: How can you find the `Sum('True', 'False')`. No Integer value is feeded to the sum() function in your query.

Comment: What do you expect to get when you do `SUM('YES')` ?? `SUM` can be applied to **numerical values** - not strings, really.....

Comment: I need to alias the column in the nested case

Comment: and I am using MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

In the first set of code each case statement is part of the SELECT list (i.e. they are in a comma separated list following SELECT) so each returns a column. In the second set of code there is only one case statement in the SELECT list, the fact that it is nested has no impact on this. Also the syntax for the nested case isn't correct because the THEN part is followed by two expressions separated by commas which is not allowed.

Comment: Is there any chance to add alias to the nested case

Comment: I don't think so, alias is only for columns and tables. In the second set of code you could give the outside case an alias by adding AS AliasName onto the end of the second from last line

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve. How is the first set of code not achieving what you want?

Comment: Of course I have achieved using the first code, but I have uploaded only a sample of the code, there are different places available in our database, so it takes more time to fetch all the values, and this query has to be added as a condition in another select stmt, so I am looking for some efficient way to do this

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific because it still isn't clear to me what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by 'there are different places available in our database, so it takes more time to fetch all the values'

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible to do what you want.  You want to create *two* columns, so each needs its own logic and its own alias:

```
SELECT id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.place = 'CHN' AND a.salary = 20000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) as Salary_20K,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.place = 'CHN' AND a.salary = 35000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) as Salary_35K
FROM Employee a;
```

Note:  Don't put numeric constants in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: As 'CHN' is common in both the cases, it is possible to check place first and if it is satisfied then we can check the salary and save it in Salary_20K and Salary_35k

Comment: @Daemon_Demon . . . You would move the condition to the `where` clause, but then it would filter out any `id` that didn't have a `CHN` row.  For a simple string comparison, though, you don't need to think about such micro-optimizations.